# How to get size of data available thru stdin with C++: When STDIN is NOT redirected

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

While [Question A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14862549/how-to-get-size-of-data-available-thru-stdin-with-c) is marked as duplicate, but the referred [Question B and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14491378/winapi-c-client-detect-write-on-anonymous-pipe-before-reading) only solve part of the problem: When STDIN is redirected.  Thus I ask the same question as [Question A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14862549/how-to-get-size-of-data-available-thru-stdin-with-c) again, when STDIN is NOT redirected.

My question: When STDIN is not redirected, how can I determine the available size in STDIN to read?   Please do not just answer using `PeekConsoleInput`, but also includes an example, as I have found no example how to use it to do the job, if possible.

[Question A and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14862549/how-to-get-size-of-data-available-thru-stdin-with-c) does mentioned that "There is no one-to-one correspondence between input events and characters", and that's why I think `PeekConsoleInput` is not a good solution to this question, since the function actually peeks events rather than input contents.  Or, perhaps someone can use `PeekConsoleInput` in some cleaver way...

--update-- @mikedu95
At first, I tested mikedu95's answer, and it seems to work.
However, the sleeping function is not what I want.  Remember the program needs to do something at the same time when it is listen to STDIN input. Thus I modify it to the following test codes:

```
    HANDLE hStdin = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    INPUT_RECORD input_record;
    DWORD nb_read, nb_chars = 0, i;
    string line;

    printf("You have 5 seconds to type some text\n");

    while (true) {
        bool status = PeekConsoleInput(hStdin, &input_record, 1, &nb_read);
        if (!status) {
            int err = GetLastError();
            cout << "err=" << err << endl;
            break;
        }

        ReadConsoleInput(hStdin, &input_record, 1, &nb_read);
        if (input_record.EventType == KEY_EVENT) {
            KEY_EVENT_RECORD record = input_record.Event.KeyEvent;
            if (record.bKeyDown) {
                if (record.uChar.AsciiChar != '\r') {
                    line += record.uChar.AsciiChar;
                    cout << record.uChar.AsciiChar;
                    cout.flush();
                } else {
                    cout << endl << "got line: " << line << endl;
                    line = "";
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

It basically works.  However, it raised another problem: I have to deal with raw keys. It catches every keys, including shift keys, back-spaces, in the `line` string in the above code.  In addition, I have to echo the key back to the console, otherwise I can not see it whiling entering texts.  I really want to use `cin.getline(buf, size)` to get a line, where I can edit the line before hitting 'Enter', and deal with the final input rather than raw inputs.

--Update--
Another thought is to use `cin.rdbuf()->in_avail()`, but it seems not working though.  A while loop checking cin.rdbuf()->in_avail() never returns values other than 0.  In fact, the in-line editing feature never triggered, and I see nothing echoed back when I typed some characters.

Comment: Do you want your program to know that I'm going to type 50 characters before I close the program, or just to know that I've typed 5 characters that it hasn't processed yet? (The former is impossible, the latter is a reasonable thing to want to do)

Comment: The later one.  I did not even mention "program close".   In fact, my program is waiting for console input, while doing something else.  The program must respond to console input.   I know another option is to use an additional thread.  However, when blocking call is used in that additional I/O thread, how do I properly kill the keyboard I/O thread, when  my main thread want the whole program to exit?

Comment: Use `PeekConsoleInput`, look for `KEY_EVENT` records. If the `UnicodeChar` field is something other than `0`, increment your counter by the value of `wRepeatCount`.

Comment: From the *Remarks* section of `ReadConsoleInput()`'s documentation (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684961%28v=vs.85%29.aspx): "*A process can specify a console input buffer handle in one of the **wait functions** to determine when there is unread console input. When the input buffer is not empty, the state of a console input buffer handle is signaled.*" "*wait functions*" links to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687069%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @alk: In fact, they all are the same.  Waiting for input buffer means waiting for input buffer event, which is the same as the event from ReadConsoleInput() or PeekConsoleInput().  Only difference is the behavior: WaitSingleObject(), WaitMultipleObject() wait, ReadConsoleInput() reads, and PeekConsoleINput() peeks the events.

Answer (score 0):

In fact you're simply looking for an example of use of PeekConsoleInput:

```
#include <Windows.h>

// Ignore events from keys like ctrl, alt, etc.
#define is_char(x) (isprint((x)) || isspace((x)))

int main(void)
{
    HANDLE hStdin = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    INPUT_RECORD input_records[50];
    DWORD nb_read, nb_chars = 0, i;

    printf("You have 5 seconds to type some text\n");
    Sleep(5000);

    PeekConsoleInput(hStdin, input_records, 50, &nb_read);
    printf("read %u input events\n", nb_read);

    for (i = 0; i < nb_read; i++) {
        if (input_records[i].EventType == KEY_EVENT) {
            KEY_EVENT_RECORD record = input_records[i].Event.KeyEvent;

            if (record.bKeyDown && is_char(record.uChar.AsciiChar)) {
                nb_chars += record.wRepeatCount;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("%u are chars\n", nb_chars);

    return 0;
}
```